# iOS - IAP problems, confused about app store receipt

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I made a game.  I didnt expect it to become wildly popular so I didn't care to write complicated cryptography code for receipt validation.  My game's IAP (to remove ads) was working perfectly in sandbox mode.  The app has been released live for about the last 16 hours and there is a problem.  The app is behaving as if everyone has purchased the "remove ads" IAP.

this is my extremely basic receipt validation code:

```
override init(){
    super.init()

    // storekit delegation
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: self.productID))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }

    self.checkReceipt()

}

func checkReceipt(){
    if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL {
        if let receipt = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            self.adsRemoved = true
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. in my sandbox environment.. the `receipt` variable wouldn't get unwrapped unless I had purchased the IAP.  `self.adsRemoved` wasn't being set to true.  It seems like on the app store itself, these variables always get unwrapped.  What's up with that?  What should i do.
2. I know now that it's standard for IAP to become active a day or two after app submission.  Could this be related to that?  I know if I hit my restore button nothing happens.  In my sandbox environment it asks for credentials.. shows a success message, etc.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there an empty receipt in production? Ie, one without any purchases? It seems you are not implementing the standard transaction observer delegate methods. Is that so? Why even check the receipt if no purchase transaction has succeded?

Comment: I don't know what an empty receipt is.  I know that on the sandbox env, if the sandbox user hasnt purchased my IAP, then no receipt is returned.  On the live app store, a receipt is always returned..  I'm checking for this receipt on each app launch.  

I am implementing the transaction observer delegate methods for a new purchase, or a restored purchase.

Comment: Receipts in >= iOS7 are containers for purchase record info. Those can (possibly; I don't recall if I've actually seen this happen) be valid non-nil containers but containing info for no purchases. The only way to discriminate this would be to decode the receipt.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. in my sandbox environment.. the receipt variable wouldn't get
>      unwrapped unless I had purchased the IAP.  self.adsRemoved wasn't
>      being set to true. It seems like on the app store itself, these
>      variables always get unwrapped. What's up with that? What should i do.

Your `checkReceipt()` method checks for the presence of the receipt at the URL given by `-appStoreReceiptURL`.

This is problematic because every app that is downloaded from the App Store **will contain a receipt, whether the app is free or paid.**

This is documented in [Apple's Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW3):

> When an application is installed from the App Store, it contains an
>   application receipt that is cryptographically signed, ensuring that
>   only Apple can create valid receipts. The receipt is stored inside the
>   application bundle. Call the appStoreReceiptURL method of the NSBundle
>   class to locate the receipt.

So why did it work for you in sandbox mode? This is because sandbox apps installed via Xcode contains no receipt, until either of the following occurs:

1. A receipt is requested via `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKReceiptRefreshRequest_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKReceiptRefreshRequest))
2. When an in-app purchase is made, or
3. When previous transactions are restored via `-restoreCompletedTransactions`

So in a nut shell, your `checkReceipt` method will definitely set `adsRemoved` to true for anyone who has downloaded your game from the App Store, because you're checking for the **PRESENCE of a receipt**, which for reasons above, does not mean anything at all to you.

What you need to be doing is validating whether the receipt is (1) legit, and (2) whether it indicates that the correct in-app purchase has been made.

> 2. I know now that it's standard for IAP to become active a day or two after app submission. Could this be related to that? I know if I hit
>      my restore button nothing happens. In my sandbox environment it asks
>      for credentials.. shows a success message, etc.

Not true that IAP takes a day or two to activate after app approval, and no—the problem occurred because you're checking for the presence of the receipt, and not validating the receipt.

Unfortunately, receipt validation is complex, but necessary if you want to achieve what you want to achieve (i.e. check if an IAP has been made). You'd want to refer to this [objc.io article on receipt validation](http://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/#validating-the-receipt) for more information about how to actually validate the receipt. At bare minimum, the steps involved are:

1. Locate the receipt, which is what you're already doing.
2. Verify the receipt is legit and not tampered with.
3. Parse the receipt to figure out the IAP has been made, because a receipt exist even without purchasing the IAP

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the receipt sending the receipt data for Apple provided url. Later, based on the response you will receive you have to set the value self.adsRemoved = true/false.

Comment: I'm not interested in validating it.  I just want to check a receipt for this IAP exists.  Again, not interested in writing complicated cryptography code to do this.  I just want to check someone has a receipt for this IAP, forged or otherwise.

Comment: I dont understand why in the sandbox environment the receipt wouldnt be found until purchase.. but in live environment receipt is always found.

Comment: @Deepak-- you definitely don't *have* to use the Apple provided URL to validate the receipt. On >= iOS7 you can do receipt validation local to the device.

Comment: @ChrisPrince -- Ohh thats great. I have one doubt. How about if there are multiple productIds? Will there be each receipt for details of each product  or only one receipt forever that contains all the purchased products details.

Comment: With >= iOS7 style receipts, this depends on the product type. For example, with non-consumable products, if the user has purchased more than one non-consumable product, receipts will permanently have the record of all of those purchases. Does that help?

Comment: Actually In my case, I am having 6 Auto-renewable products with one month duration each in my app. Before user goes to access the content, I need to check the validity of the respective product id. So, how the best approach will be for this.